# Minicart blank only on product page magento 2 getting knockout js error!

Tags: product, product-view, mini-cart, magento2.1.5, sidebar

I am using an extension WeltPixel_QuickCart for minicart sidebar. It is working fine on all pages except product detail page.

Knockout js error showing in the console on product page:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return getTemplate() }"
Message: getTemplate is not defined
    at template (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2624), <anonymous>:3:61)
    at init (pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js:5023)
    at pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2989
    at Object.ignore (pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js:1249)
    at pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2988
    at Object.arrayForEach (pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js:151)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2974)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2854)
    at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js:2836)
    at Object.ko.applyBindingsToDescendants (pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js:3052)
```

How can I fixed the issue?

Comment: Knokout could not getting template, please share full console log.

Comment: I have added console error in question, are you talking about exception.log

Comment: No, I am talking about browser console log, have you costumized anything related to minicart on product page in XML or in other file?

Comment: No, nothing customized for product page.

Comment: Have you done any customization related to product page?

Comment: No, I have not.